# Dielectric tensor in the RPA

Tags: dielectric, many-body

The dielectric function in the random phase approximation (RPA) is written as

$\epsilon^{RPA}(\mathbf{q},\omega)= 1 + v_c(q) \Pi(\mathbf{q},\omega)$,

where $v_c(q)$ is the Fourier-transformed Coulomb potential and $\Pi(\mathbf{q},\omega)$ is the polarizability. In the RPA, $\Pi(\mathbf(q), \omega)$ is given by

$\Pi(\mathbf{q},\omega) = -2\sum_{j,j'} \int \frac{d^2 k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{f_{j,k}-f_{j',k+q}}{E_{j,k}
-E_{j',k+q}-\hbar \omega + i\eta}|\langle \Phi_{j,k}| \Phi_{k',k+q} \rangle|^2$,

for a two-dimensional system, where $f_{j,k}$ are the Fermi-Dirac distributions. Is there an equation for the dielectric tensor components in the RPA?